# Select a specific form on change of dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 form that I want to show on change of dropdown option.

Means when select form1 in option Form1 should come and when select form2 in option form 2 should come.

How can I do that please give me suggestion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secelt Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1() {
    document.getElementById('form1');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Form 1</label>
<form  method="post"  name="firstform" id="form1" action="">
<button id="btn1" value="Select All">Select All</button>
<button id="btn3" value="Delete CheckBox">Delete CheckBox</button>  <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="One" id="ck1">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Two" id="ck2">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Three" id="ck3">Three</input<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Four" id="ck4">Four</input>br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Five" id="ck5">Five</input>br>
<button id="btn4" value="Status"">Status</button>
</form><hr>

<label>Form 2</label>
<form name="secondform" id="form2" action="">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br><br>
<button id="btn5" name="chk" >Submit</button>
</form><hr>

<label>Select Form</label>
<select id="select1" onchange="">
<option></option>
<option onselect="fun1()">Form 1</option>
<option>Form 2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: copy your code to snippet, so that it will be clear to solve

Comment: what you trying to do?

Comment: do you want to display form based on option selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secelt Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setForm(value) {

    if(value == 'form1'){
                document.getElementById('form1').style='display:block;';
                document.getElementById('form2').style='display:none;';
            }
            else {

                document.getElementById('form2').style = 'display:block;';
                document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:none;';
            }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form1">
<label>Form 1</label>
<form  method="post"  name="firstform" action="">
<button id="btn1" value="Select All">Select All</button>
<button id="btn3" value="Delete CheckBox">Delete CheckBox</button>  <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="One" id="ck1">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Two" id="ck2">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Three" id="ck3">Three</input<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Four" id="ck4">Four</input>br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Five" id="ck5">Five</input>br>
<button id="btn4" value="Status"">Status</button>
</form><hr>
    </div>
<div  id="form2" style="display: none">
<label>Form 2</label>
<form name="secondform" action="">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br><br>
<button id="btn5" name="chk" >Submit</button>
</form><hr>
</div>
<label>Select Form</label>
<select id="select1" onchange="setForm(this.value)">
<option value="form1">Form 1</option>
<option value="form2">Form 2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your posted code - but just in the interest of answering your original question - the following will allow you to toggle the display state of each form. I would strongly recommend reworking them - but the mechanism of the solution is to hide the forms on the load and then  based on the selected option - display one or the other form.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('#selectForm').change(function(){
    var formID = $(this).val();
    $('form').css('display','none');
    $('#'+formID).css('display','block');
})
  
  })
```

```css
form{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secelt Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<label>Select Form</label>
  <select id="selectForm">
    <option></option>
    <option value="form1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="form2">Form 2</option>
</select>
<hr/>

<form  method="post"  name="firstform" id="form1" action="">

<label>Form 1</label>
<button id="btn1" value="Select All">Select All</button>
<button id="btn3" value="Delete CheckBox">Delete CheckBox</button>  <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="One" id="ck1">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Two" id="ck2">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Three" id="ck3">Three</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Four" id="ck4">Four</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Five" id="ck5">Five</input><br>
<button id="btn4" value="Status">Status</button>
</form>

<form name="secondform" id="form2" action="">
<label>Form 2</label>
Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br><br>
<button id="btn5" name="chk" >Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1() {
    var xx = document.getElementById('select1').value;
    fun2();
    if(xx==1)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(xx==2)
    {
        document.getElementById('form2').style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
function fun2()//to hide all form elements
{
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form  method="post"  name="firstform" id="form1" action="">
<label>Form 1</label><br>
<button id="btn1" value="Select All">Select All</button>
<button id="btn3" value="Delete CheckBox">Delete CheckBox</button>  <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="One" id="ck1">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Two" id="ck2">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Three" id="ck3">Three</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Four" id="ck4">Four</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Five" id="ck5">Five</input><br>
<button id="btn4" value="Status">Status</button><hr>
</form>


<form name="secondform" id="form2" action="">
<label>Form 2</label><br>
Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br><br>
<button id="btn5" name="chk" >Submit</button><hr>
</form>

<label>Select Form</label>
<select id="select1" onchange="fun1()">
<option ></option>
<option value="1">Form 1</option>
<option value="2">Form 2</option>
</select>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
fun2();//to hide form elements after page has loaded completely
</script>
</html>
```

I have written in pure javascript but Jquery would be simple

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding about your Question. You want to show the form which is selected in Dropdown.

Here I modify your code for same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secelt Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function HidebothForm()
{
document.getElementById("form2id").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
           document.getElementById("form1id").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
function fun1() {

    var e = document.getElementById('select1');
    var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selectedOption == "frm1")
          {
           document.getElementById("form2id").style.visibility = "hidden";
           document.getElementById("form1id").style.visibility = "visible";
            }

         else if(selectedOption == "frm2")
          {
           document.getElementById("form2id").style.visibility = "visible";
           document.getElementById("form1id").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
            }
else
{
HidebothForm();
}



}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="HidebothForm()">

<div id="form1id">
<label>Form 1</label>
<form  method="post"  name="firstform" id="form1" action="">
<button id="btn1" value="Select All">Select All</button>
<button id="btn3" value="Delete CheckBox">Delete CheckBox</button>  <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="One" id="ck1">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Two" id="ck2">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Three" id="ck3">Three</input<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Four" id="ck4">Four</input>br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="Five" id="ck5">Five</input>br>
<button id="btn4" value="Status"">Status</button>
</form>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="form2id">
<label>Form 2</label>
<form name="secondform" id="form2" action="">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br><br>
<button id="btn5" name="chk" >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<hr>

<label>Select Form</label>
<select onchange="fun1()" id="select1">
<option></option>
<option value="frm1">Form 1</option>
<option value="frm2">Form 2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you.